# ZKTeco SDK for Php / Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sdk

I have Attendance Management Device of Zkteco Brand

https://www.helptechco.com/content/K20

i need SDK of Php or Javascript,

i have tried some sdk like tad-php , zklib but not getting success yet

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://www.zkteco.com/en/product_detail/ZKFingerSDK5.3.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That SDK [TAD/PHP](https://github.com/cobisja/tad-php) worked for me. The steps are -

1. edit your **php.ini** and enable the following extension (remove **';'** from the front) and restart apache

   `extension=soap extension=sockets`
2. Then connect the device with your PC via **TCP/IP**. e.g-

   > Ip Address(PC) =192.168.1.202
   >   Default Gateway(PC) =192.168.1.201
   >   Ip Address(Device) =192.168.1.203
3. Then follow the **readme** file in **TAD/PHP** and connect according to the given instruction.e.g-

   `$tad = (new TADFactory(['ip'=>'192.168.1.203', 'com_key'=>0]))->get_instance();`

Comment: can you please tell me which device did you use?

Comment: Tested on 2 devices.
1) ZKTeco F18
2) ZKTeco UA500

Comment: @imrankhan i use ZKTeco F18 device, the above method returns false device status. I dig into the code and found the library is using CURL to communicate with device but when i try to communicate using raw Curl script it comes with "Connection reset by peer"

Do you know what can the cause of connection refuse??

Comment: remove the password from device then check either it works or not

Comment: Imposible iniciar conexión con dispositivo ******.*****.com, other php libs works..